# How to create table in HTML that contains computed numbers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Basically if I have 2 text fields (m1 and b1), where the user would input whatever numbers they want, I want to create a table in html with 2 columns (x and y), where the x column would consist of X values from 0 to 5, while the y column would consist of outputs of plugging in the x values into y = mx + b, where m and b come from the user input into fields m1 and b1. This would be in real time

For example, if the user inputs m1 = 2 and b1 = 1, then we would have y = 2x+1, so the table should consist of:

x   y

0   1

1   3

2   5

And so on. This is the code for the text fields where I will be getting the data.

Slope

```
        <div>
          <label>Y Intercept</label> <br /><br />
          <input id="rangeInputB" type="range" min="-10" max="10" step = "0.25" oninput="b1.value=rangeInputB.value" />
          <input id="b1" type="number" value="1" min="-200" max="200" oninput="rangeInputB.value=b1.value" />
        </div>
```

This is my attempt at a table, and I understand that it is treating the y = m1 * x + b1 as a string:

```
  <table>
          <tr>
            <th>X</th>
            <th>Y</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-5</td>
            <td>-5 * m1 + b1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Thank you!
This is the code if you want to see: https://jsfiddle.net/csCoder/eLxfrn10/17/

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```js
// logic
const params = {
  get xs() {
    return [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  get m() {
    return inM.valueAsNumber
  },
  get b() {
    return inB.valueAsNumber
  },
  get calc() {
    return (x) => this.m * x + this.b
  }
}

const inM = document.getElementById("input-m")
const inB = document.getElementById("input-b")

inM.addEventListener("change", function() {
  updateTable({ m: params.m, b: params.b, xs: params.xs })
})

inB.addEventListener("change", function() {
  updateTable({ m: params.m, b: params.b, xs: params.xs })
})


// row template
const getRowHtml = ({ m, x, b }) => `<tr><td>${x}</td><td>${params.calc(x)}</td></tr>`

// table template
const getTableHtml = ({ m, b, xs }) => xs.map(x => getRowHtml({m, x, b})).join('')

const updateView = (tbody) => ({ m, b, xs }) => {
  tbody.innerHTML = getTableHtml({ m, b, xs })
}


const tbody = document.getElementById("table-body")
const updateTable = updateView(tbody)

// initial update
updateTable({ m: params.m, b: params.b, xs: params.xs })
```

```html
<div>
  X: <input id="input-m" type="number" value="0" />
  b: <input id="input-b" type="number" value="0" />
</div>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>y</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```